# Plot words with coordinates

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame which looks something like this:

```
word   x     y
"and"  0     0
"the"  0.5   0.4
"some" 1     1
"get"  -0.3  0.4
....
```

I'd like to plot words from `word` to coordinates `(x, y)`.

ggplot would be preferable.

Comment: Have you already tried something?

Comment: @Marki555 I admit I was fast to turn to SO, I will try to avoid such behavior in the future. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
require(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  words = c("These","Are","Words"),
  x = c(1,2,3),
  y = c(1,2,3)
)

ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_text(aes(x = x, y = y, label=words))
```